# How to execute single function in multiple thread and thread instance create in loop in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

1) i have a list of product links and it contain 3385 links

2) i have a function get_pro_info(link) it take link of product and append item to the json file.

3) i want selenium open 5 browser and 5 link parallel and get information of product and append in a file or list..

or 3) selenium open 1 browser and 5 tab(having 5 links) and append file.

Question how can i apply threading on my code?

my code...

```
new_url=''
def get_pro_info(pro_url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Beenu\PycharmProjects/chromedriver.exe')
    try:
        new_url = 'https://pk.studiobytcs.com' + pro_url
        print('new product URL: ' + new_url)
        driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
        sleep(1)
        # use to switch control
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
        # sleep(1)
        driver.get(new_url)
    except(WebDriverException, selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException, Exception) as e:
        print('There is error in getting Product by URL in get_pro_info()! \n' + str(e.stacktrace))
        pass
    description_source_code = ''
    # description_soup = BeautifulSoup()
    description_soup: BeautifulSoup = object
    # global description_soup
    try:
        # description_soup = BeautifulSoup('html.parser')
        description: WebElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="shopify-section-product-template"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]')
        description_source_code = description.get_attribute("innerHTML")
        description_soup: BeautifulSoup = BeautifulSoup(description_source_code, 'html.parser')
    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        print('Product description taag not found! \n' + str(e.stacktrace))
        pass
    # 179 here
    # This is for getting heading product name
    head = ''
    r_j_title = ''
try:
    head = description_soup.find_all("h1", class_="product_name")
    # print(head)
    r_j_title = head[0].string.strip()
    print("Title: " + r_j_title)
except (HTMLParser, IndexError):
    print('Fail to get heading/title Tag! \n' + str(HTMLParser))

# This is for get brand name from heading/title
r_j_brand_and_designer = ''
try:
    brand_and_designer = head[0].string.strip().split("-")[0]
    r_j_brand_and_designer = str(brand_and_designer).strip()
    print('Brand and designer: ' + r_j_brand_and_designer)
except (IndexError, ValueError) as e:
    print('Fail to Split Brand from heading/title ! \n' + str(e.stacktrace))

# This is for getting price in integer
r_j_price_in_int = ''
try:
    price = description_soup.find_all("span", class_="money")
    # print(price)
    price_new = price[0].string.strip()
    print("New price: " + price_new)
    # this is for getting price from string
    r_c_price = price[0].string.strip().split(".")[1]
    r_j_price_in_int = str(r_c_price).replace(",", "")
    # price could ha ,
    print('Price: ' + r_j_price_in_int)
except (HTMLParser, IndexError, ValueError) as e:
    print('Fail to get Tag or failed to Split Brand from heading/title ! \n' + str(e.stacktrace))

# this is for getting full description
description_all = ''
r_j_desc = ''
try:
    description_all = description_soup.find_all("div", class_="description")
    final_des = str(description_all[0].get_text())
    ch = final_des.split()
    r_j_desc = str(' '.join(ch))
    print("with split ch : " + r_j_desc)  # addtion of .string.strip()
except (HTMLParser, IndexError, ValueError) as e:
    print('Fail to get all description Tag or failed to Split and removing endline chr from description ! \n' + str(
        e.stacktrace))

#   This is for trying if fibric tag is not avaliable
try:
    get_split_fibric = description_all[0].get_text().split("Fabric", 1)[1]
    get_split_des = get_split_fibric.split("Disclaimer")[0]
    r_j_fabric = str(get_split_des).strip()
    print("getting fibric: " + r_j_fabric)
except IndexError as e:
    r_j_fabric = 'N/A'
    print('Fabric is not avaliable: ' + r_j_fabric)

item['brand_name'] = str(r_j_brand_and_designer)
item['designer'] = str(r_j_brand_and_designer)
item['title'] = str(r_j_title)
item['description'] = str(r_j_desc)
item['price'] = int(r_j_price_in_int)
item['currency'] = "PKR"
item['product_id'] = str(r_j_title)
item['source'] = str(new_url)
item['fabric'] = str(r_j_fabric)
item['gender'] = "woman"

print(item)
cloth = {
    "cloth": item
}
# instruction
print(cloth)
list_before_dump.append(cloth)

driver.close()
driver.quit()

with open('product_link_read.txt', 'r') as file:

data = file.readlines()
# rd_pro_link_list=rd_pro_link_list+data.replace('\n', '')

print(data)
for line in data:
    # fap=
    rd_pro_link_list.append(str(line).strip())

print(rd_pro_link_list)
print(len(rd_pro_link_list))

for pro_link in rd_pro_link_list:
get_pro_info(pro_link)
print('Pro count = ' + str(pro_count))
pro_count = pro_count + 1

list_before_dump_file.write(json.dumps(list_before_dump))
driver.close()
list_before_dump_file.close()
```

Comment: first 20 links `list_of_product_link[:20]`

Comment: and what about for the next 20 links it will automatically iterates next 20?

Comment: next 20 links `list_of_product_link[20:40]`

Comment: i want to iterat whole list it contain around 3000 links in it.. how this is possible with loop

Comment: see my answer for loop

Comment: you changed all question. Now it doesn't fit to my answer. If you have new question then use button "Add Question" to create new question on new page. Eventuall append new information at the end of existing question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to iterate list and get always 20 links then you can use `range(start, stop, step)` with `step=20`

```
all_t = []

for i in range(0, len(list_of_product_link), 20):
     twenty_links = list_of_product_link[i:i+20]

     t = threading.Thread(target=get_product_info, args=(twenty_links,))
     t.start()
     all_t.append(t)

# --- later ---

for t in all_t:
     t.join()
```

or

```
for i in range(0, len(list_of_product_link), 20):
     twenty_links = list_of_product_link[i:i+20]

     all_t = []

     for link in twenty_links:    
          t = threading.Thread(target=get_product_info, args=(link,))
          t.start()
          all_t.append(t)

     # --- inside first `for` loop ---

     for t in all_t:
         t.join()
```

Other method is good if you will no need later your list

```
all_t = []

while list_of_product_link:
     twenty_links = list_of_product_link[:20]
     list_of_product_link = list_of_product_link[20:]

     t = threading.Thread(target=get_product_info, args=(twenty_links,))
     t.start()
     all_t.append(t)

# --- later ---

for t in all_t:
     t.join()
```

or

```
while list_of_product_link:
     twenty_links = list_of_product_link[:20]
     list_of_product_link = list_of_product_link[20:]

      all_t = []

     for link in twenty_links:    
          t = threading.Thread(target=get_product_info, args=(link,))
          t.start()
          all_t.append(t)

     # --- inside first `for` loop ---

     for t in all_t:
         t.join()
```

---

BTW: `args=` needs tuple - even if you have only one arguments so you need `,` in `( )` to create tuple with one element.

---

BTW: If you want it to run only 20 threads in every moment then better see [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and `Pool(20)`

```
 from multiprocessing import Pool

def get_product_info(link):
    result = ....
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(20) as p:
        all_results = p.map(get_product_info, list_of_product_link)
```

Comment: Thanks i'm trying and i'll let you know if i got some error..

Comment: t = threading.Thread(target=get_product_info, args=(twenty_links,))
here you are giving list to the function but i want to give one link to each thread and create 20 thread at a time?

Comment: do you have any other source where i can show you full code? here i can't put more character?

Comment: i didn't know why you need 20 links - some people sends 20 links to one thread so they don't have to create thread again and again. But you can use loop to run 20 threads.

Comment: see new code in answer - now there are two version with `args=(twenty_links,)` and with `args=(link,)`.

Comment: using `Pool()` you can get similar result using only 3-4 lines.

Comment: you can add code to your question but don't change previous text/code. You can also start new code with word `**EDIT:**`

Comment: i have post my question more clear and with code please review and solve my problem i'm stuck from couple of days..

Comment: i apply your code for twenty links list and it's open 100s of browser..

Comment: you changed all question - it is out of the rules in stackoverflow.

Comment: as I remeber in first version you wanted to get 20 links and you didn't say you want to open 20 threads - and version with `args=(twenty_links,)` does it. It create lists with 20 links but it doesn't care how many thread it will create. If you have 3000 links then 3000/20 gives 150 sublists and it should create 150 threads. Second version uses for loop with `args=(link,)` and it should create only 20 threads and they should close browsers at the end. The same with `Pool(20)`.

Comment: okay sorry i'll change as previous...you mean when we give list of 20 link to threading.Thread it create 20 thread?

Comment: no, if I use `twenty_links` then it create one thread but this thread get 20 links and I could use `for`-loop in this thread to get data from these links. If you have 3000 links and you split it into 20 lists with 150 links in every list then you can create 20 threads and every thread can get 150 links and every thread can use `for`-loop to get data from these 150 links. This way you create 20 threads only once and you have 20 threads all time, and you don't have to delete thread when it get data from one link and create new thread to get data from another link. BTW: similar way works Pool(20)

Comment: BTW: `Pool(20)` also control to get results in correct order. System may run threads in different orders and you can get results in random order.